# Do I need a Visa for Canada if I fly from Mexico?

Tags: visas, canada, mexico, cambodian-citizens

I have plan to visit Mexico, and I also want to visit Canada. Do I need a Canada Visa if I fly from Mexico?

Comment: Your citizenship?

Comment: Sorry i forgot mention it. I am Cambodia citizen

Comment: Please edit that information into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a visa for Canada is required separately.

There is no Exemption that allows a Cambodian citizen to visit Canada without a visa regardless of where the trip originates from.

Source: [Timatic via Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=KH&NV=Cambodia&DC=CA&DV=Canada&TC=MX&TV=Mexico&h=c171ee13cae9baf7fe5a61e66fa464ac7491ce)

Comment: Thanks. Do i need to apply for Canada visa in my country or in Mexico?Because i will go visit Mexico first.

Comment: From your own country it make much more sense, you aren't a resident of Mexico and applying fora visa to a third country from a second country where you are just a tourist for a few days isn't a very strong base at all.

Comment: @SamphosChea I suggest you do apply online instead of applying from one country or another. Start now. You may be required after you do the application to visit an office close by to get your fingerprints and biometrics but that is after you prepare an online application and submit it.